# Restore role visibility in blocks

Tags: 8, blocks

I upgraded my Drupal 8 site from 8.4.5 to 8.5 and I noticed the role visibility in blocks disappears. I did a clean install and it's in Drupal Core, so the problem is not with my upgrade. I am thinking it's in the database but I have no idea how to track it. Does anyone know how?

Comment: This is a known bug and will be fixed in 8.6

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2952962

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Solved it by editing the content of the block.
(we logged in as admin you see a button in the right upper corner, click it and select Edit). It appeared the the translated content was not published.

Comment: Editing the block is not the problem. The missing Roles visibility option is.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to /admin/people
2. Edit your admin account
3. Ensure the "admin" checkbox is checked under the Roles section.

Comment: Sorry, turns out this *can* fix the problem but it's not guaranteed. Basically it depends on whether the user doing the block editing is a valid user or not. It can be this, if the problem is a permissions issue, rather than the actual bug that was found.

Comment: True! However, we are here to answer timely questions, not fix bugs in Drupal core :D Can we get an updated answer for people who newly find this page?